# Как составить алгоритм поиска всех вариантов разбиения матрицы (двумерного массива)

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, математика, матрицы

Как найти все варианты разбиения матрицы (двумерного массива) на N равных по площади прямоугольных частей.
Например, имеем матрицу 3х3 (неважно какими числами заполнены ячейки)

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Все варианты разбиений:

1) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (при площади 1)

2) 1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9 (при площади 3)

2) 1 4 7, 2 5 8, 3 6 9 (при площади 3)

Как составить алгоритм? Помогло бы и просто описание словами или на js, или любой другой язык.

Comment: А если 4x4 - нужны все разбиения на 1x1, 1x2, 2x2, 1x4?

Comment: *Как составить алгоритм?*. Для каждого измерения отдельно получаем полный список его кратных (от 1 до самого числа). Составляем все возможные пары. Если надо, выбрасываем вариант с единственной областью размером во всю матрицу. Profit. Всё это при условии, что НЕ требуется вращений, иначе алгоритм дополняется субпроцедурой поиска всех вариантов покрытия области плашками равного заданного размера, с отсеиванием дубликатов.

Comment: @MBo да, только будет еще 2x1 и 4x1, т.е. в другом порядке

Comment: @Akina, да, с кратными понятно, вопрос как раз в том как составить эти всевозможные пары, т.е. как найти все возможные комбинации разбиения

Comment: 4x4 можно покрыть разными плашками. А можно 2x1 и горизонтальными, и вертикальными. Это нужно?

Comment: @MBo, да, это и все такие